# DELETE data in DATATABLE in Flet with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flet

Hello I'm doing a CRUD in Flet with Python so far my CRUD works well with adding, now I want to do to delete the data from the DataTable but using an **IconButton** that when pressing the IconButton I delete the data from the DataTable but I get this message: **TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

```
import flet as ft
from flet import *


def main(page: ft.Page):

    codpro = TextField(label="CÓDIGO PRODUCTO")
    nompro = TextField(label="NOMBRE PRODUCTO")

    #combo de categoria
    ddcate = ft.Dropdown(label="CATEGORIA",
        width=150,
        options=[
            ft.dropdown.Option("dulce"),
            ft.dropdown.Option("salado"),
        ],
    )

    #combo de peso
    ddpeso = ft.Dropdown(label="PESO",
        width=100,
        options=[
            ft.dropdown.Option("KG"),
            ft.dropdown.Option("G"),
        ],
    )


    tablaproducto = DataTable(
                  #CABECERA DE LAS CALUMNAS  
                  columns=[
                      DataColumn(Text("CÓDIGO")),
                      DataColumn(Text("PRODUCTO")),
                      DataColumn(Text("CATEGORÍA")),
                      DataColumn(Text("PESO")),
                      DataColumn(Text("ACCIONES")),
                  ],
                  #FILAS  
                  rows=[]          
    )

    #FUNCION ELIMINAR
    def eliminar(e):
        tablaproducto.rows.remove(tablaproducto.rows)

        #MENSAJE con Barra inferior
        page.snack_bar = SnackBar(
            Text("SE ELIMINO DATO", size = 30),
            bgcolor = "red"            
        )
        page.snack_bar.open = True
        #FIN DEL MENSAJE inferior
 
        page.update()

    

    #FUNCION para AGREGAR     
    def agregar(e):
        tablaproducto.rows.append(
            DataRow(
                cells=[
                    DataCell(Text(codpro.value)),
                    DataCell(Text(nompro.value)),
                    DataCell(Text(ddcate.value)),
                    DataCell(Text(ddpeso.value)),
                    DataCell(
                        Row([
                        IconButton("delete", 
                                   icon_color ="red",
                                   on_click = eliminar),
                        ])
                        ),
                ]
            )
        )
        #MENSAJE con Barra inferior
        page.snack_bar = SnackBar(
            Text("DATO INGRESADO CORRECTAMENTE", size = 30),
            bgcolor = "green"
        )
        page.snack_bar.open = True
        #FIN DEL MENSAJE

        page.update()

       
    #Boton AGREGAR
    BtnAgregar = ElevatedButton(
        text="Agregar", 
        bgcolor="blue",
        color="white",
        on_click=agregar
        )
    

    page.add(
        Column([
            Text("PRODUCTOS",size=30,weight="bold"),
            codpro, nompro,ddcate, ddpeso,
            Row([BtnAgregar]),
            tablaproducto
 
            ])
 
        )


ft.app(target=main)
```

I'm doing a CRUD in Flet with Python so far my CRUD works well with adding, now I want to do to delete the data from the DataTable but using an **IconButton** that when pressing the IconButton I delete the data from the DataTable but I get this message: **TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve with this line of code

```
def eliminar(e):
        tablaproducto.rows.remove(tablaproducto.rows[0])

        #MENSAJE con Barra inferior
        page.snack_bar = SnackBar(
            Text("SE ELIMINO DATO", size = 30),
            bgcolor = "red"            
        )
        page.snack_bar.open = True
        #FIN DEL MENSAJE inferior
 
        page.update()
```